# Merge is multiplying data frames when it should left merge

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames "cb" and "ca" which share a column name "Item", with elements of the same type (factor). Yet, left-merge fails to produce a data frame of the same size as the x data frame. What am I missing?? Many thanks in advance.

```
ca <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,2,1), Item = c("1","1","2","2","2"))
cb <- data.frame(B = c(2,3,1,2), Item = c("1","1","2","2"))
t <- merge(cb,ca, by = "Item", all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
```

Merge results in:

```
   Item B A
1     1 2 1
2     1 2 2
3     1 3 1
4     1 3 2
5     2 1 3
6     2 1 2
7     2 1 1
8     2 2 3
9     2 2 2
10    2 2 1
```

> 

But what I need is:

```
> t
Item A B
1    1 2
1    2 3
2    3 1
2    2 2
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question.

Comment: Highly likely due to duplicates in the data. For instance, if there are multiple "B"s associated with single key ("Item") in data "cb", then, you will have more number of rows in resulting data frame

Comment: You use `all.x=TRUE` and yet your output has fewer rows than `ca`.

Comment: in your expected output you have Item 1, A 3 and B 3. But there is no record of 1 and A 3. what are trying to do here?

Comment: You need to explain your expected output a bit more. For starters, there is no "item 1 A 3" in your data, but you have it in your output.

Comment: Apologies, Matt & r2evans. Typo corrected.

Answer (score 1):

As @won782 suggesed, it is likely due to duplicates. Here is a small MWE demonstrating what duplicates (on both sides) will do to a merge.

First, we have no duplicates:

```
ca <- data.frame(A = 1:4  , Item = 1:4)
cb <- data.frame(B = 11:13, Item = 1:3)
merge(ca, cb, by = "Item", all.x = TRUE)
#   Item A  B
# 1    1 1 11
# 2    2 2 12
# 3    3 3 13
# 4    4 4 NA
```

If we introduce dupes into the "left" side, all looks good still:

```
ca <- data.frame(A = 1:4  , Item = c(1L,1:3))
cb <- data.frame(B = 11:13, Item = 1:3)
merge(ca, cb, by = "Item", all.x = TRUE)
#   Item A  B
# 1    1 1 11
# 2    1 2 11
# 3    2 3 12
# 4    3 4 13
```

When we have duplicates in the right side, though, each matching row on the left is duplicated appropriately. Namely, see "Item 1"

```
ca <- data.frame(A = 1:4  , Item = 1:4)
cb <- data.frame(B = 11:14, Item = c(1L,1:3))
merge(ca, cb, by = "Item", all.x = TRUE)
#   Item A  B
# 1    1 1 11
# 2    1 1 12
# 3    2 2 13
# 4    3 3 14
# 5    4 4 NA
```

Notice how 4 rows in `ca` produced 5 rows in the merge.

If we have dupes in both sides, it explodes a little. Now we have "Item 1, A 1" twice" (same for "A 2"):

```
ca <- data.frame(A = 1:4  , Item = c(1L,1:3))
cb <- data.frame(B = 11:14, Item = c(1L,1:3))
merge(ca, cb, by = "Item", all.x = TRUE)
#   Item A  B
# 1    1 1 11
# 2    1 1 12
# 3    1 2 11
# 4    1 2 12
# 5    2 3 13
# 6    3 4 14
```

There are several good tutorials on merging data. Don't limit yourself to searching for "R merge", you can find a lot with searches for "SQL join" as well (adding "tutorial" and/or "howto" to those searches might be helpful).

Bottom line, though, is that there is no "general answer" for this problem, as it is actually "by design". Anything other than this cartesian join would require either data reduction or use of another key (existing or additional) for clarifying how you want things to join.

Comment: Thank you,  that clears it up. I've updated my original post with a simple example explaining what the goal is. Now I need to determine which command is appropriate, since "merge" is not the correct option.